# Room persistent library different hash for Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-room

When i open AndroidStudio project, that was created on machine with Ubuntu, on Windows machine identity hash changes.
It caused by different \n.

Ubuntu variant

```
"createSql": "CREATE  INDEX `index_invites_creator_fb_id` ON `${TABLE_NAME}` (`creator_fb_id`)"
```

Windows variant

```
"createSql": "CREATE  INDEX `index_invites_creator_fb_id`\nON `${TABLE_NAME}` (`creator_fb_id`)"
```

Any suggestion for avoiding this issues?

Comment: That sounds like a bug. IMHO, the hash shouldn't pay attention to whitespace anyway. If you can create a simple reproducible test case, consider [filing an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:197448&p=1).

Comment: Somebody filed the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64470691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in Android Architecture Components 1.0.0 Alpha 9-1.